# Windows Service слушает 25 порт

Tags: c#, service, tcp-ip, windows-service

Добрый день.

Мне требуется написать Windows Service, который слушает 25 порт.
Собственно я его и сделал - в командной строке пишу

> telnet localhost 25

и далее идет диалог с сервисом.
Задумка такая - я отправляю почту (например через оутлук), она отправляется через 25ый порт,мой сервис ловит подключения, и вместе отправки имейла делает свои действия (отправку СМС).

**Скажите, я на правильном пути?**

Слушаю я 25ый порт так:

```
SMTP_Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 25);
SMTP_Listener.Start();
```

Я стараюсь не использовать никаких сторонних разработок типа wincap'а.

Спасибо.

Comment: Если в аутлуке в качестве smtp сервера явно указан ip адрес на котором слушает ваша программа - то да

Comment: @Mike оформите как ответ, я отмечу решенным. Спасибо !